# SAML 2 | Refresh IdP Session when user is working on SP

Tags: session-management, saml

Wanted to discuss the solution and options to refresh the IdP Session when user is actively working on the SP.

The use case is that after successful SP-Initiated SSO, there are two sessions in picture:

- IdP (SSO) Session
- SP Session

When user is actively working on the SP Pages, there is no explicit communication between SP and IdP. This will result in IdP session timeout. To avoid this timeout, the IdP session needs to be refreshed.

To best of my understanding SAML Specs don't provide for this use case.

So, in my view the IdP session would need to be '*explicitly*' refreshed either by Passive SAML Request or by invoking an IdP API for session refresh.

Please confirm if my understanding is correct and any other options.

PS: I think in case of OpenAM, this use case case is handled by web policy agents but not all IdPs provide agents.

Comment: that's the way I understand it too, but am curious to see if anyone has any more definitive answers